# Trigger: System.Exception: Too many code statements: 200001

Tags: apex-code

I am receiving this error when trying to update the contact object.

Trigger: System.Exception: Too many code statements: 200001

Trigger :

```
trigger Points_FromContact_Trigger on Contact (after delete, after update) {
    //This is an empty list of contacts that will contain all General contacts from our DML action
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    //This is a string variable to hold the  Contact Record Type -  General recordTypeId
    String General = RecordHandler_GetRecordTypeId.getId(EnvironmentClass_RecordTypeNames.General, Schema.Sobjecttype.Contact.getName());
    if(trigger.isDelete) //If the DML action was a delete...
    {
        //... for every contact in the delete action...
        for(Contact c: trigger.old)
        {
            //... if the contact record type is the General...
            if(c.RecordTypeId == General)
            {
                //... then add the contact to our list of contacts.
                contacts.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    else //This is an insert/update DML action.
    {
        //For every contact in the DML action...
        for(Contact c: trigger.new)
        {
            //... if the contact record type is the ES Contact Record Type - General...
            if(c.RecordTypeId == General)
            {
                //... then add the contact to our list of contacts.
                contacts.add(c);
            }
         }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please, format the code in proper way so we can read it normally.

Comment: I have modified the post, please add your comments

Comment: Are you mass deleting or inserting/updating records? Or is there anything else happening in this trigger that is not shown?

Comment: I am updating contacts through data loader.

Comment: @Rajeev Okay, keep in mind that you can only execute 200000 code statements (ie. code lines) per request. The data loader probably updates the records in bulks large enough for your trigger to execute more lines. See if you can reduce the number of records that are updated. Otherwise, maybe you can use workbench.developerforce.com or dataloader.io, with these tools I know you can reduce the batch size.

Comment: Thanks Kex!! . I want to update the trigger instead of reducing the batch size. Is there any way we can optimize it.

Comment: @Rajeev As far as I can see there isn't really room to improve the code. There are just two lines that are executed within the loop, so you should be able to process almost up to 100000 records.

Comment: What is a value of trigger.new.size()?